# Sun X4170 squealing after disk eject. How do I fix this?

Tags: raid, hardware, sun

I just ejected one of the "hot swappable" hard drives from a Sun X4170 running RAID 10 and it is making quite a loud noise. It's like a system beep that's one long continuous note.

I'm wondering what is causing this and how I fix it. Preferably fast as it is driving me mad (it's in the office for setup and testing).

We are running ESXi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HDD had not reconnected properly when being reinserted into the server. Removing and reinserting the drive correctly stopped the noise and the RAID resynced.

Answer (score 0):

This is typically a "hardware failed" warning, and is supposed to alert DC techs that something needs replacing.  You typically tell the machine to quiet down via IPMI (or whatever the Sun equivalent is) or an OS-specific tool that talks to the hardware.  If you provide your OS details, it's likely someone will be able to give you the exact invocation you need (I'm not real up to speed on Sun hardware).

Comment: It's running ESXi